# SQL Oracle merge two rows into one

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I have looked everywhere but can't not really find my answer on here.
The table the query is about:

```
Temptable

id   Value  P   money1    money2     difference
1    B      O   100       null       -100
1    B      S   null      100        100
1    E      O   100       null       -100
1    E      S   null      100        100
1    O      O   100       null       -100
1    O      S   null      100        100
2    B      O   456       null       -456
2    B      S   null      456        456
2    E      O   456       null       -456
2    E      S   null      456        456
2    O      O   456       null       -456
2    O      S   null      456        456
```

What I want is to combine the row's with the same id.
So that after the query the result should be:

```
id   Value  P   money1    money2     difference
1    E      O   100       100        0
1    E      S   100       100        0
1    B      O   100       100        0
1    B      S   100       100        0
1    O      O   100       100        0
1    O      S   100       100        0
2    E      O   456       456        0
2    E      S   456       456        0
2    B      O   456       456        0
2    B      S   456       456        0
2    O      O   456       456        0
2    O      S   456       456        0
```

So if id 1 money2 is null, the value should be filled with the id 1 where money2 is filled in. This because I need to have the records which the difference is smaller than one and the table is delivered with the values on different columns.

Comment: Wouldn't one row per id be better?

Comment: That could also be an option, I really just need the rows combined. I don't know if deleting a row would be better or not.

Comment: Will every unique Id have only 2 records?

Comment: I edited the table and the expected result, every id will have 6 records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you just need a group by:

```
SELECT t.id,
       t.value,
       SUM(money1) AS money1,
       SUM(t.money2)  AS money2,
       SUM(difference) AS difference
  FROM temptable t
 GROUP BY t.id, t.value
```

**Edit:** I see you changed the sample data. You could get the new result using analytic functions:

```
SELECT t.id,
       t.value,
       t.p,
       SUM(t.money1) OVER (PARTITION BY t.id, t.value) AS money1,
       SUM(t.money2) OVER (PARTITION BY t.id, t.value) AS money2,
       SUM(difference) OVER (PARTITION BY t.id, t.value) AS difference
  FROM temptable t
```

This way, you will print all the rows

Comment: Your answer gives me exactly what I want! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sadly, after really checking it I have noticed that if I leave the P out of the partition by all the money is combined. So for id 1 I get everywhere 300. If I set the P in the partition by the money isn't filled like my example result but the sum of column1 is filled everywhere in column 1 and the same for column2

Comment: Why? Partition by is on both id and value. As for your sample data, you should get 100, because you only have two rows for every id/value combination

Comment: You could also partition by only id, when you calculate money1 and money2, if you use MIN() or MAX() rather than SUM(). This way, you will get the max non-null value over all 6 rows of the id. I'm not sure though what you're trying to do now

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, `value`, SUM(money1) money1, SUM(money2) money2, SUM(difference) difference
FROM Temptable
GROUP BY id, `value`;
```

Answer (score 2):

Tro to use this by contribution of `sum` and `nvl` :

```
select max(id) id, value, 
       sum(nvl(money1,0)) money1, sum(nvl(money2,money1)) money2,
       sum(nvl(money2,money1)) - sum(nvl(money1,0)) difference
  from Temptable
 group by id, value;
```

Comment: If i use this, all the null values change to 0 but not the value I want.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is a `update`, not `MERGE`, using `COALESCE` or `NVL`

```
UPDATE Temptable
SET  money1 = COALESCE(money1, money2)
    ,money2 = COALESCE(money2, money1)
    ,difference = COALESCE(money1, money2) - COALESCE(money2, money1);
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0c7dc/1)